# MongoDB project nested element in _id field

Tags: mongodb, mongo-c-driver

I'm stuck in something very stupid but I can't get out from my own.

MongoDB v4.2 and I have a collection with documents like this:

```
{"_id":{"A":"***","B":0}}, "some other fields"...
```

I'm working on top of mongo-c driver and I want to query only the "_id.B" field but I don't know how I can do it. I have tried:

1. "projection":{"_id.B":1}: It returns me the whole _id object. _id.A & _id.B.
2. "projection":{"_id.A":0,"All other fields except _id.B":0}: Returns same as above.
3. "projection":{"_id.A":0,"_id.B":1}: Returns nothing.

How I can do it to get only some object elements when this object is inside the _id field? The first option works for me with objects that aren't inside the _id field but not here.

Best regards, thanks for your time.

Héctor

Comment: Is this useful: [Finding Fields using Dot Notation](http://mongoc.org/libbson/current/parsing.html#finding-fields-using-dot-notation).

Comment: I think not. This is for driver documents in memory and my question is about stored documents in MongoDB. But thanks you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MongoDB's [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html) in aggregation to do this. You can also use `$addFields` to get `_id.B` into new field + all other fields in document & finally project `_id :0`.

**Code:**

```
var coll = localDb.GetCollection("yourCollectionName"); 

var project = new BsonDocument 
{ 
    { 
        "$project", 
        new BsonDocument 
            { 
                { "_id.B": 1 }
            } 
    } 
}
var pipeline = new[] { project };
var result = coll.Aggregate(pipeline);
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DKKzH6MK9az)

Comment: Thanks. Why is necesarry an aggregation pipeline to do such simple operation? Isn't possible to do it with the basic  [find](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/command/find/) command?

Comment: @Héctor : It seems to be `.find()` is not capable of doing this..